# spring security - dynamic roles

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security, role

I have a user in my application that needs to be exposed to some data by category.
for example:
user A with ROLE_CAMPAIGN can see only WHERE **campaign**_category_id = 5
user b with ROLE_CAMPAIGN can see only WHERE **campaign**_category_id IN(5,10,4)
(select,insert,update,delete)

User and Campaign are hibernate entities.
their connection is ManyToMany (User has CampaignsCategories )
If I translate that to **native** SQL

```
SELECT * FROM CAMPAIGNS WHERE CATEGORY_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM USER_CATEGORIES)
```

and on and on.

What is the correct way to implement dynamic to a user with some role.

Little example will help.

(Spring security 3)

Comment: Is category an attribute of user?

Comment: Sorry, Edit the post, this is a attribute of a campaigns

Comment: How Compaign is configured? Is it a Spring bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could use the Access Control Lists (ACL) for solving this issue: 2 employees have the same ROLE_EMPLOYEE and can't do what an admin can, yet within that perimeter they are not allowed to see or delete each other's record.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html shoud give you a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a technical solution to a security model shortcoming.

**People in the same roles should have the same access.**

If you find that your security decisions do not follow this condition then you need to redefine roles to be more granular.

Comment: Or not use roles to cover this sort of access control. Spring Security can do more than just RBAC, but that's the form that is best supported.

Comment: @Donal: yes, I agree but given the nature of the question that didn't seem to be what the OP was looking for, but maybe it is.

Comment: So, What is your thoughts about how to implement such of stick structure. I mean, it is very common situation that a certain employee can see his own data and yet he is ROLE_EMPLOEE. I believe that spring security covers that, this is a security issue. thanks

Comment: What I have personally done is create a role for "self" and that self role is added to the user if their user principle matches the resources target.

Comment: Can you please explain... or give an example? complicated to cover in one sentence thanks (-:

Answer (score 0):

Roles is not the answer that you are looking for. Access Control Lists is the solution to your problem as stated by Emanuel. Spring security when configured to use roles, cannot natively distinguish between two users having same roles.

Answer (score 0):

NORMALLY, RBACs cannot give different permissions per controlled entity. RBACs are two dimensional - Permissions X ROLE. There are not usually any mechanisms for testing which content is being controlled. You could probably use an RBAC for this, but it would take a lot of ROLES to do it, and some customizations and you'd end up creating an ACL anyways.

ACLs on the other hand, inherently are 3 dimensional - Permissions X ROLES X Object are all capable of being defined against each other in full sets, or partial sets:

Permissions X ROLE X Object (ACL in full)
Permissions X ROLE (RBAC)
ROLE X Object (useful?)
Permissions X Object (useful?)

BOTH ACLs and RBACs allow assigning people different ROLES. MOST RBACs don't allow assigning permissions any other way.

However, many ACLs have the ability to assign permissions directly to people in regards to specific Objects/Entityes. If this is a cpability of an ACL, it adds a great deal of flexibilty at a huge increase in complexity and loss of speed. it's far better to just create a ROLE specifically for one person. So don't go there with direct assignment of permissions to people.

Your problem is MOSTLY that you aren't differentiating the types of ROLES, but an RBAC wouldn't do it for you anyway. You should use an ACL. If you can set up a tabular display of permissions vs ROLE, and ROLE vs object, you'll keep your understanding longer.

One more element that most good ACLs have: Groups of Objects. That is what you need to do bulk or 'as you go' assignments of permissions. Your creation code for Campaigns would pre assign the groups by the category, and the ROLES and permissions would then happen naturaly.